# In Android Swipeable Tab's ,How to restrict user to not to go to next Tab2 until he fills the data in Tab1

Tags: android, tabs

In Android Swipeable Tab's ,How to restrict user to not to go to next tab until he fills the data in Tab1.I was struck here

I tried in the following way:

@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (item == 0) {
            System.out.println("0");
              //I am calling static method in Fragment 1 to check whether user filled all fields or 
              //not 
            fragment = new FragmentOne();

```
    }
    if (item == 1) {
        System.out.println("1");

        fragment = new FragmentTwo();

    }
    if (item == 2) {
        System.out.println("2");
        fragment = new FragmentThree();
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

But It is not working ,please let me know if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: make the return value of getCount() as 1 till the fragment is filled.

Comment: But at the Activity is loaded(Main Activity which holds all the 3 fragments) this First Fragment will not be initialed so If I try to create an object for First Fragment it is giving "null pointer exception",If I use static method I can't use non static variable(edit text ,ect..) to validate whether to check user filled those fields or not

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your comment.
initialize your fragment after the activity is created. when the fragment one fields are filled, change adapter getcount() to 2.
to communicate between activity and fragment use interface